# mysqli query inside loop does not work properly, only insert first iteration

Tags: php, mysqli

I have this mysqli query but it only inserts the first iteration. But when I comment the insert statement and just echo the values, the loop works fine.

```
$max = count($_SESSION['cart']);
for($x=0; $x<$max; $x++) 
{
    $product = $_SESSION['cart'][$x]['product_desc'];
    $quantity = $_SESSION['cart'][$x]['quantity'];
    $sql = "insert into waybills (product_desc, quantity) values ('$product', '$quantity')";
    mysqli_query($link, $sql);
}
```

Is there any error that is making the loop not working?

Comment: `echo $product; echo $quantity;` and what do you see? Any values? and put a `if(!mysqli_query($link, $sql)) { // Query Failed.";` instead.

Comment: I have figure the issue. I was due to the index set for one of the fields